# how to remove local from flywheel

Tags: localhost

I installed [local from flywheel](https://localwp.com/). It's not what I want, my little laptop is begging for mercy. How do I remove it? They have instructions for apple and windows, but not for ubuntu.

Comment: How did you install it?

Comment: I downloaded the deb package from the site.

Comment: Hmmm... It seems to run in a virtual machine, apparently VirtualBox. So either remove the relevant virtual machine or uninstall VirtualBox itself (if you don't need it). Or ask at https://localwp.com/community/search?q=ubuntu.

Comment: The solution depends on which Ubuntu release you're running. Please Edit (https://askubuntu.com/posts/1216030/edit )

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a debian / apt-get based OS the following command will remove software from you system. The first part uninstall the software and the second part removes any extra software that was installed but is no longer needed.

> sudo apt-get remove [package name] && sudo apt-get autoremove

In the command above you need to replace '[package name]' with the name of the package you want to remove. In the case of local by flywheel, the name is localwp. So it becomes:

> sudo apt-get remove localwp && sudo apt-get autoremove

You can also take it one step further and remove the configuration along with the software by using purge. This can only be done when the software is still installed.

> sudo apt purge [package name]